# Why are ANSI escape codes being rendered "textually" in my VS Code remote connection (MacOS to MacOS)

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I am not sure where this problem originates from: I am using VS Code in a remote environment (both client and remote are Macs) to develop a Ruby on Rails application. However when I try to debug in the console within VS code (I am using pry, but something similar happened with the debug gem), the up / down keys do not work - they produce weird characters (which I now know are ANSI escape codes) but they don't actually do what they are supposed to do (scroll through previous commands). I think I need to set my key bindings / mapping somewhere but I am not sure where to do that?

What is the cause of this problem, and how can it be prevented from happening again in the future?

Comment: show a screenshow and copy paste the text of the weird symbols. Are they by any chance [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_(Control_Sequence_Introducer)_sequences)?

Comment: Yes. I just tried to reproduce the problem, it doesn't seem to exist any longer but they were ANSI escape codes.