# Force debug console to handle ANSI escape codes

Tags: visual-studio-code, ansi-escape

I have a problem [similar to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74543649/why-are-ansi-escape-codes-being-rendered-textually-in-my-vs-code-remote-connec), however, I am not using remote debugging. Moreover, the question has no answer at all.

I am using a library, Point Cloud Library, that shows warnings and errors with ASCII escape codes. VSCode does not handle them well in the debug console:

```
e[1;33m[pcl::PLYReader::listPropertyDefinitionCallback] no fitting callbacks. element_name=face, property_name=vertex_indices
e[0;me[1;33m[pcl::PLYReader] /Users/.../sphere.ply:9: property 'list uint8 int32 vertex_indices' of element 'face' is not handled
```

Right now I have VSCode 1.78.2 (Universal) on macOS 13.3.1 (22E261).

Is it any possibility of fixing this?

Comment: just to be clear- this isn't in the terminal panel? at least from [this issue ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/21423) it seems implied that ANSI escapes are supported in the debug console.